# error 1503 while installing solr 9 with nssm

Tags: solr, windows-services, command-prompt, nssm

Error 1053 - Service do not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I am installing solr 9.1.1 version using nssm. The path to executable was repeatedly setting to nssm.exe path. But I explicitly changed to solr.cmd path.

Now I am getting another error - [Error 1053 - Service do not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7plvp.png)

Path seems fine. I don't find any issue and don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: I have added the key in regedit as well for servicePipeTimeout - 180000. I cannot restart server though as this is on virtual machine.
Any other way to reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the error. The issue was I downloaded wrong package.
Downloaded latest from https://solr.apache.org/downloads.html.
earlier package was incomplete - without required jar files.

so downloading new package worked.